# Can I simplify this css with sass?

Tags: html, css, layout, sass

I was just able to answer my own question:
[trying to replicate the layout "fit as needed" or "Ram" for IE 11 but items are being stretched when they should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738124/trying-to-replicate-the-layout-fit-as-needed-or-ram-for-ie-11-but-items-are)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* border: 4px solid blue; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: darksalmon;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  /* 100% / [# of columns] - ([gap]*([# of columns]-1)/[# of columns]) */
  width: calc(99.9999% / 4 - ((20px * 3) / 4));
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  max-width: 1fr;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item:nth-child(4n) {
  background: burlywood;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
  background: purple;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 859px) {
  .item:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
  }
  .item {
    /* 100% / [# of columns] - ([gap]*([# of columns]-1)/[# of columns]) */
    width: calc(99.9999% / 3 - ((20px * 2) / 3));
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
  }
  .item:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3n) {
    background: burlywood;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 1) {
    background: pink;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 639px) {
  .item:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
  }
  .item {
    /* 100% / [# of columns] - ([gap]*([# of columns]-1)/[# of columns]) */
    width: calc(99.9999% / 2 - ((20px * 1) / 2));
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
  }
  .item:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-child(2n) {
    background: lightskyblue;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
    background: midnightblue;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 419px) {
  .item:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
  }
  .item {
    /* 100% / [# of columns] - ([gap]*([# of columns]-1)/[# of columns]) */
    width: calc(99.9999%);
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
  }
  .item:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .item:nth-child(n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .item:nth-last-child(-n + 1) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if the css part that re-divide the columns and set the margins to fake the gap can be simplified with sass. I have little none experience with it. So any help would be appreciated.

Note that as the number of column decreases I have to override the previous width and the nth-child margins plus add the new rule as you will see, 4n,3n... -n + 4, -n + 3... .There, you see the pattern and that is what I want to simplify.

PS: just ignore the fact that adding more items will break this. this is not that important. But if you know an easier way I would be glad to know as well.

PS2: I tried to use the gutter grid mixin for the gaps.

```
http://gutter-grid.net/
```

But seemed too convoluted just for that.

PS3: The same situation with the css tricks tut, also for the gaps.

```
https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-faking-an-auto-placement-grid-with-gaps/
```

I would need to wrap each item with a div plus mix padding with margins.

Comment: There are a few things in your code that can be simplified (sass or no sass), also clean up 60-70% of it. You want to make it grid and fallback to flex, or, just to be able to have a gap with flex? Do you want it to work in IE11?

Comment: wht not using `flex`?

Comment: @Greedo he is using flex?

Comment: yes, in this case he can get ridden of many lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this, the "trick" here is to use negative margins on the grid, with that you can reduce your css to this.

This is IE prof. If you like to use SCSS you could add a variable `$gap: 20px;` and use that in the places where you have `20px`, remember in the calc you have to use it like this `calc(50% - #{$gap})`

Just to comment on your previous css. In IE, calc does not support multiple calculations, so this wont work: `calc((100%/2) + 10px)`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.item {
  background: deeppink;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (min-width: 420px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 860px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the calc totally works for IE. in width you can use without issues. you probably are talking about other properties that does not support inner calc.

Your is similar to the css tricks which I already tried and you are introducing the same problem there. which is this weird spaces after the items, right and bottom.

Another thing is that when it reaches the min-width of 200px. it should stack in your sample it is not like that, might be the way you changed the media queries?

Thanks
If you can show me how I can fix this extra blank spaces I can accept this answer.

Comment: @RicardoSilva, the calc issue is there in IE for width, https://caniuse.com/?search=calc, look at tab: know issues, nr 9, I also know by own experience doing the exactly same thing as this. I updated the answer, there was a miss on my part with a scss variable was left in the code. Try this now. The min-width, do you want that to dictate when it should go to next row but still keep the breakpoints? That approach is a bit different from what you tried doing.

Comment: Ok I can accept this, thanks for taking the time, there is still the problem with the bottom not filling up, but I think we can fix that with height: calc(100% + $gap)